# Avoid AppleScript to make line breaks

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm using this AppleScript to get the content of a selection of eMails:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on run {input, parameters}
        set mailContents to {}
        repeat with aMessage in input
            set end of mailContents to content of aMessage
        end repeat
        return mailContents
    end run
end using terms from
```

The result looks like this:

```
{"￼
  ￼
Here's some text followed by a longer URL, which is cut by a line break!  

http://www.XYZ.net/diario/actualidad/economia/20140714/-ciudad-bar
ata-para-el-turismo_353_34541.html

"}
```

I want to use all links in those specific mails for fort her processing but it's not possible to use  the divided URLs as seen in the example before. 
So how to tell the AppleScript to keep the URL together?

Comment: if EVERY URL link gets split into two paragraphs, then just inside your repeat loop, search for the line in aMessage that begins with "http:" and remove the paragraph mark at the end of it.

Comment: Thanks @jweaks! Just the URLs which are to long for a line get split. Any idea how the remove the paragraph mark? I tried dozen different ideas but wasn't able to reach that. ;(

Comment: well, it'd be easy to use the do shell script grep line to match the line and remove the paragraph mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much! I had to customize your script a bit because not every URL ends with `html`. Furthermore I used the `source` of the messages instead of `content`, because the deleted line breaks had the result, that it was very difficult to separate the URLs from other text. There was no space between them. This is my actual code:
`using terms from application "Mail"
    on run {input, parameters}
        set mailContents to {}
        repeat with aMessage in input
            set end of mailContents to source of aMessage
        end repeat

```
    set httpLinks to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of mailContents
        set thisContent to item i of mailContents

        -- remove all return characters (mac, unix, and windows characters)
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"=09", "=" & character id 10, "=" & character id 13, "3D", character id 92}
        set textItems to text items of thisContent
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
        set newText to textItems as rich text

        -- find links
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "http"
        set textItems to text items of newText
        if (count of textItems) is greater than 1 then
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "target"
            repeat with j from 2 to count of textItems
                set linkItems to text items of (item j of textItems)
                set thisLink to "http" & item 1 of linkItems & "target"
                set end of httpLinks to thisLink
            end repeat
        end if
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

    end repeat

    set list1 to httpLinks
    set list2 to {}
    repeat with x from 1 to count of items of list1


        set n to item x of list1
        if n is not in list2 then set end of list2 to n
    end repeat

    return list2



end run
```

end using terms from`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I started with your mailContents example. You end up with a list of the links in the httpLinks variable. This works assuming every link starts with "http" and ends with "html". Good luck.

```
set mailContents to {"￼
  ￼
Here's some text followed by a longer URL, which is cut by a line break!  

http://www.XYZ.net/diario/actualidad/economia/20140714/-ciudad-bar
ata-para-el-turismo_353_34541.html

"}

set httpLinks to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count of mailContents
    set thisContent to item i of mailContents

    -- remove all return characters (mac, unix, and windows characters)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {character id 10, character id 13, character id 13 & character id 10}
    set textItems to text items of thisContent
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set newText to textItems as text

    -- find links
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "http"
    set textItems to text items of newText
    if (count of textItems) is greater than 1 then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "html"
        repeat with j from 2 to count of textItems
            set linkItems to text items of (item j of textItems)
            set thisLink to "http" & item 1 of linkItems & "html"
            set end of httpLinks to thisLink
        end repeat
    end if
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
end repeat

return httpLinks
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to customize your script a bit because not every URL ends with `html`. Furthermore I used the `source` of the messages instead of `content`, because the deleted line breaks had the result, that it was very difficult to separate the URLs from other text. There was no space between them. You may have a look to the code, which I now use! Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This does not break lines, hope you can use it somehow:

```
tell application "Mail"
  set mailSelection to selection
  set mailContents to {}
  repeat with mail in mailSelection
    set end of mailContents to content of mail
  end repeat
  get mailContents
end tell
```